# Python Optimization For calculation of eucledian distance

Tags: python

This function is being run more than 2 million times in my program. Can anyone suggest to optimize this?
x and y are tuples.

```
def distance(x,y):

    return sqrt((x[0]-y[0])*(x[0]-y[0])+(x[1]-y[1])*(x[1]-y[1])+(x[2]-y[2])*(x[2]-y[2]))
```

My try:  I tried using math.sqrt, pow and x**.5 but there is not much performance gain.

Comment: What are you doing with the final `distance`? If you're only using it for comparison, drop the `sqrt` and square the thing you're comparing against.

Comment: If you know C, I would use that language. Python is known to be an inefficient mathematician.

Comment: if the value x[i]-y[i] repeats often you can try caching `(x[i]-y[i])*(x[i]-y[i])`

Comment: You might be interested in the tools provided by [scipy.spatial.distance](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/spatial.distance.html).

Comment: @MarkRansom- Good point but removing sqrt is also not helping much. More than 2 million computations are taking around 34 seconds but for the same algorithm author of paper has done it in 1 sec using Java with similar hardware configuration(his RAM: 4GB, mine 3GB else is same). Could it be a problem of language as I am using python?

Comment: Python is about 50x slower than native code, so that sounds pretty normal.

Comment: What kind of data is this being evaluated on? If you can compute this using NumPy, it will be about as fast as the Java code.

Comment: Function provided above is computed millions of time and different answers are compared together to get to the result. So this function is like the heart of program.

Comment: as suggested by @BrenBarn, [scipy.spatial.distance.euclidian](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.euclidean.html#scipy.spatial.distance.euclidean) would be already optimized for that purpose

Answer (score 3):

you can shave off some cycles by not accessing same x[i] element and binding it locally.

```
def distance(x,y):
    x0, x1, x2 = x
    y0, y1, y2 = y
    return sqrt((x0-y0)*(x0-y0)+(x1-y1)*(x1-y1)+(x2-y2)*(x2-y2))
```

example, compare:

```
>>> import timeit
>>> timer = timeit.Timer(setup='''
... from math import sqrt
... def distance(x,y):
...    return sqrt((x[0]-y[0])*(x[0]-y[0])+(x[1]-y[1])*(x[1]-y[1])+(x[2]-y[2])*(x[2]-y[2]))
... ''', stmt='distance((0,0,0), (1,2,3))')
>>> timer.timeit(1000000)
1.2761809825897217
```

with:

```
>>> import timeit
>>> timer = timeit.Timer(setup='''
... from math import sqrt
... def distance(x,y):
...    x0, x1, x2 = x
...    y0, y1, y2 = y
...    return sqrt((x0-y0)*(x0-y0)+(x1-y1)*(x1-y1)+(x2-y2)*(x2-y2))
... ''', stmt='distance((0,0,0), (1,2,3))')
>>> timer.timeit(1000000)
0.8375771045684814
```

There are more [performance tips on the python wiki.](http://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonSpeed/PerformanceTips)

Answer (score 2):

scipy has a euclidian distance function. You probably won't get any faster than that.

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.euclidean.html#scipy.spatial.distance.euclidean

```
from scipy.spatial.distance import euclidean
import numpy as np

# x and y are 1 x 3 vectors
x = np.random.rand(1,3) 
y = np.random.rand(1,3)
euclidean(x,y)
```

EDIT: Actually, running this through timeit against OP's pure-python distance() function, this is actually turning out to be way slower on python floats. I think the scipy version wastes some time casting the floats to numpy dtypes. I'm quite surprised to say the least.

Answer (score 1):

Original:

```
>>> timeit.timeit('distance2((0,1,2),(3,4,5))', '''
... from math import sqrt
... def distance2(x,y):
...     return sqrt((x[0]-y[0])*(x[0]-y[0])+(x[1]-y[1])*(x[1]-y[1])+(x[2]-y[2])*(x[2]-y[2]))
... ''')
1.1989610195159912
```

Common Subexpression Elimination:

```
>>> timeit.timeit('distance((0,1,2),(3,4,5))', '''
... def distance(x,y):
...     d1 = x[0] - y[0]
...     d2 = x[1] - y[1]
...     d3 = x[2] - y[2]
...     return (d1 * d1 + d2 * d2 + d3 * d3) ** .5''')
0.93855404853820801
```

Optimized Unpacking:

```
>>> timeit.timeit('distance((0,1,2),(3,4,5))', '''
... def distance(x,y):
...     x1, x2, x3 = x
...     y1, y2, y3 = y
...     d1 = x1 - y1
...     d2 = x2 - y2
...     d3 = x3 - y3
...     return (d1 * d1 + d2 * d2 + d3 * d3) ** .5''')
0.90851116180419922
```

Library Functions:

```
>>> timeit.timeit('distance((0,1,2),(3,4,5))', '''
... import math
... def distance(x,y):
...     x1, x2, x3 = x
...     y1, y2, y3 = y
...     d1 = x1 - y1
...     d2 = x2 - y2
...     d3 = x3 - y3
...     return math.sqrt(d1 * d1 + d2 * d2 + d3 * d3)
... ''')
0.78318595886230469
```

Dotted:

```
>>> timeit.timeit('distance((0,1,2),(3,4,5))', '''
... from math import sqrt
... def distance(x,y):
...     x1, x2, x3 = x
...     y1, y2, y3 = y
...     d1 = x1 - y1
...     d2 = x2 - y2
...     d3 = x3 - y3
...     return sqrt(d1 * d1 + d2 * d2 + d3 * d3)
... ''')
0.75629591941833496
```

Comment: you want to avoid the dotted notation and have `from math import sqrt` rather than calling `math.sqrt` and incur penalty for each call.